# vi backspace problem

Tags: vi

I have to work on a really old AIX workstation with vi version 3.10 in it.
I have done a little work in vim, but that was much more easy to use than the old vi (atleast untill I get used to the old vi).

Since I have been using the backspace key to erase my previous character for ever since I was born, I would like to have that functionality in vi as well.

I did search for a solution.

I found the following:

1. `:set backspace=2` (:set all does not have a backspace option, nor nocompatible)
2. `stty erase ^?`  (Didn't work)
3. In .exrc file in my home directory, I can set up a mapping. ie, map  .

However, in the edit mode in vi, pressing backspace actually takes my cursor to one position on the left, but does not remove it.

How do I map a supposedly arrow key to make it perform the function of a backspace?

AIX Version: 5
5300 something. uname -a gives AIX << hostname >> 3 5

Comment: In the insert mode: backspace = move cursor one step left
del = Change case of character
In the command mode: backspace = function of delete or x
del = Change case of character

Comment: When you enter new characters after pressing backspace in edit mode, do they replace old ones?
Also, AIX gurus may want to know that AIX version are you using.

Comment: No they dont. It simply places the cursor to one char left of the current, without deleting it. I believe version is AIX 5

Answer (score 2):

Try

> `:map` <kbd>Backspace</kbd>  `X`

You’ll have to type a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> immediately before the <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, and so the command will probably look like

> `:map  ^H  X`